# getting FileNotFoundException when trying to read an excel file from resource directory

Tags: java, maven-2, jexcelapi

I am getting FileNotFoundException when trying to read a .xls file from src/main/resources

```
InputStream is = ReportGenerationServiceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/bqp_template.xls");
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<build>
     <resources> 
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes><include>**/bqp_template.xls</include></includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below statement:

```
InputStream is = ReportGenerationServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bqp_template.xls");
```

**Note:** Your xls file should be directly placed in src/main/resources folder

Comment: @Amit, Have modified the java statement. In pom build tag its not mandatory to give resources entry. By default it will take everything inside src/main/resources

Comment: thanks Dinal, tried above code change but still getting error.

Comment: Did you try removing the resources entry in pom.xml and doing a clean install. Also just make sure the file is present in the war file created.

Comment: yes have removed resources entry and cleaned and installed still getting. This is a simple java app not a webapp have checked jar file and it contains the .xls file

Comment: We are following the exact same thing in our project and it works without any issues. Can you try out one last thing. Can you place the xls file in the same package of ReportGenerationServiceImpl and execute `InputStream is= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("bqp_template.xls");`. This doesn't go with maven rules, but is the simplest way to test.